# Javascript: the minimum date that is always less than any other date

Tags: javascript, string, date, compare

I want to compare strings that are dates

```
if (user_date < date)
```

date has `yyyy-mm-dd` format, so it is OK to compare dates as strings, if the user enters a valid `user_date` in this format.

Unfortunately, `user_date` is entered by the user, so it could be invalid. In case if it is invalid (or left empty), I want (user_date < date) always to be true.

I have found to set `var user_date='';` if user's date is invalid. Is that a good way to make make `(user_date < date)` for any valid date?

The same question is for `(user_date > date)` (more than any date).
I've found to set `var user_date='A';`

I need it for

```
if (date1 <= date && date2>= date)
//do something
```

**So it works without any additional `if then`.**

P.S. I don't want to enter `var user_date='2222-12-31';` because the algorythm will stop working properly in less than 210 years.

Comment: why don't you work with javascript date directly, like `new Date($userdate)` and then compare the dates

Comment: you can validate the date first, and then check if it is greater or not...

Comment: @TheBronx: I don't want to add an additional validation. 2 additional if/else will duplicate the same code.

Comment: @Arun P Johny  Sorry. Do you recommend me to connect some .js libraries?

Comment: what kind of library are you looking for

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. I've never use it before. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is not possible. But what is possible is to get a date for which a comparison is always false — so functionally it behaves the same as `NaN` does for numbers. So if you invert the test, thus replace `(a <= b)` with `!(a > b)`, it would work.

```
$date = new Date(NaN);
if (!($date1 > $date) && !($date2 < $date))  ...
```

p.s. What's with the dollar signs? Are you confusing Javascript with PHP or Perl? :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not set your min to be 0000-01-01 and your max to be 9999-12-31 ?

Comment: I agree with 0000-01-01. What about 9999-12-31, that date will be passed one day.

Comment: True, but there will be a new date format invented for that, and we will all be retired :)

Comment: Why comparing to 'A' is worse in this case? Any date until '9999-12-31' is less than 'A'. :) Moreover, you'll see my code will work on '10000-01-01' too! :)

Comment: Comparing to 'A' will work, but is fairly obscure for anyone else who may look at this code in the future. Comparing with valid date strings makes it much clearer what's going on. It may even be clearer for yourself if you come back to modify this code in a years time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do somethin glike

```
var date = '2013-03-12';
var $date = new Date(date);
function onChange(el){
    var user_date = el.value;
    var udate = new Date(user_date);
    if(isNaN(udate.getTime()) || udate < $date){
        alert('less')
    }

}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZRWp2/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would first validate the date that the user is entering - don't leave it to chance.

I use my own date extensions library here for this kind of stuff:

[DP_DateExtensions](http://depressedpress.com/javascript-extensions/dp_dateextensions/)

The parseFormat() method will let you easily validate your input. Something like this so do well:

```
Date.parseFormat(InputString, "YYYY-M-D")
```

The function returns a valid JavaScript date if the entered string matches the format or null if it doesn't.  You obviously don't have to send a user message based on this if you have a default behavior you'd like to apply - but the code itself should "know".

In this case - if you want an invalid date to be less than another, known good date, then there are many ways to do it. Most simple is something like this:

```
InputDate = Date.parseFormat(InputString, "YYYY-M-D");
if ( InputDate || InputDate < GoodDate ) {
     Input Date is Invalid or Falls before good date
} else {
     Input Date is Falls after good date
};
```

You don't need to set "false dates" or guess with the right validation and Boolean logic in play and it will work until the world stops spinning (in theory).

You can you use the compare() method in the library to do any kind of greater/less than comparison to any precision.

Hope this helps.